# VarChar MySQL Row HTML Contents Reduced on Output

Tags: html, mysql, varchar

I have a row in a MySQL table with varchar property

```
<abbr title="Twitter Handle without @ symbol" rel="tooltip" style="border-bottom:1px dotted;text-decoration:none;color:#00F303;display:inline-block;height:1.18em;">Twitter Handle</abbr>
```

When this entry is called on my webpage, the HTML contents are stripped to just display

```
<abbr title="Twitter Handle without @ symbol">Twitter Handle</abbr>
```

Leaving out `rel` and `style` attributes.

Is this occuring due to varchar limitation, or something on server not parsing entry properly?

Comment: That won't happen by itself. So either the value in the table isn't what you think, or your code to display it is removing attributes. You need to post the code.

Comment: `varchar` doesn't know anything about HTML, it won't remove stuff from the middle of a string. The only "limitation" is the length you specify, and it will just cut it off at the end.

Comment: Okay, thank you, that was informative.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure of root problem, but I was able to use Jquery to get what I was looking for

```
<script>
$("[css unique selector]").attr('rel', 'tooltip');
</script>
```